# Download image with Ruby RIO gem

Tags: ruby, download, io

My code:

```
require 'rio'
rio('nice.jpg') < rio('http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3134/3160515898_59354c9733.jpg?v=0')
```

But the image downloaded is currupted. Whtat is wrong with this solution?

Comment: in order not to confuse readers I think this question needs a 2016 update: I've just tested in recent versions of both ruby and jruby  on [linux](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rondinif/0ea22e516eb5e90ffe9600b555987211/raw/7561893bf7d030c94db957e44011b5e0f2f741e6/so-test_ruby-rio_573116@linux) and [os x](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rondinif/165ee318bc04e20bd53276f61447b506/raw/e5e4dd0d2792c839ad3ba730a992139d7d93bd88/%2520so-test_ruby-rio_573116@os%2520x) without reproducing the problem and getting images not corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a bug. On windows all 0x0A replaced with 0x0D 0x0A. And as so, it makes sence that properly used (with .binmode) it works on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

pjb3 is correct.  You must call [binmode](http://rio.rubyforge.org/classes/RIO/IF/RubyIO.html#M000008) on the left-hand term:

```
rio('nice.jpg').binmode < rio('http://...')
```

If this still does not work (notably, it may happen for large jpeg files, i.e. rio uses an intermediate temp file when retrieving from the URL you have provided), then apply the `binmode` modifier to both terms:

```
rio('nice.jpg').binmode < rio('http://...').binmode
```

---

### 2011 UPDATE

According to Luke C., the above answer no longer applies to more recent versions of the gem:

> Neither of these work. On Linux having .binmode set on the destination causes a Errno::ENOENT exception. Doing: rio('nice.jpg') < rio('http://...').binmode works

Comment: I tryed both, but still get equally corruped images. All 0x0A replaced with 0x0D 0x0A. May be a bug?

Comment: Neither of these work. On Linux having .binmode set on the destination causes a Errno::ENOENT exception. Doing: rio('nice.jpg') < rio('http://...').binmode works.

Comment: @Vertis, well, it HAS been over two years since the question was asked and answered -- maybe, just MAYBE things have changed in `rio` since, don't you think?

Comment: @vladr that's completely true. However the answer is no longer correct. Since this comes up in search results (how I found it), I think it's important to note.

Comment: @Luke, Updated the answer to reflect your findings in a more prominent place than the comments; the search engines should pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.  Are you on windows?  It might be because the file isn't being opened with the binary flag.

Comment: Yes, I am on Vista. It looks like 'rio' converted all LF (0x0A) into CRLF (0x0D 0x0A). Also, I noticied it does this in case of simple files: rio('unix.txt') > rio('win.txt'). Are you on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems downloading images on Linux, I found that this worked for me:

rio(source_url).binmode > rio(filename)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some simple ruby code to download an image

```
require 'net/http'
url = URI.parse("http://www.somedomain.com/image.jpg")
Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
  resp, data = http.get(url.path, nil)
  open( File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "image.jpg"), "wb" ) { |file| file.write(resp.body) }
end
```

This can even be extended to follow redirects:

```
require 'net/http'
url = URI.parse("http://www.somedomain.com/image.jpg")
Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
  resp, data = http.get(url.path, nil)
  prev_redirect = ''
  while resp.header['location']
    raise "Recursive redirect: #{resp.header['location']}" if prev_redirect == resp.header['location']
    prev_redirect = resp.header['location']
    url = URI.parse(resp.header['location'])
    host = url.host if url.host
    port = url.port if url.port
    http = Net::HTTP.new(host, port)
    resp, data = http.get(url.path, nil)
  end
  open( File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "image.jpg"), "wb" ) { |file| file.write(resp.body) }
end
```

It can probably be prettied up some, but it gets the job done, and is not dependent on any 3rd party gems! :)

Answer (score 0):

For downloading pictures from the web page, you can use ruby gem `image_downloader`